# CSS and JS file not linking in node js

Tags: node.js, express, static-files

I want to use middleware func to serve static file,but the problem is that my css file is not linking with html file using node and express

error is:

```
Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:4000/static/css/style.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
```

app.js:

```
const express=require('express');

const path=require('path');

const app=express();


app.use('/public',express.static(path.join(__dirname,'static')));


app.get('/',(req,res)=>{

   res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'static','index.html'));

});

app.listen(3000);
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="/static/css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="asd">
          Hi xyz here..
          
    </div>
    <script src="/static/js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

folder structure is:

```
 static

   css

     main.css

   js

     script.js

   index.html

 app.js
```

I tried a lot , but i am not able to find the error,
please help!!
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We will have to do something like that:

**app.js**

```js
const express=require('express');

const path=require('path');

const app=express();


app.use('/public', express.static(path.join(__dirname,'./static')));


app.get('/',(req,res)=>{

   res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'static','index.html'));

});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("Starting at", 3000);
});
```

**index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="/public/js/main.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="asd">
          Hi xyz here..
    </div>
    <script src="/public/js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

Here is the screenshot:

[image: Final Image]

---

A basic thumbs rule we can think of:

```
app.use('<something_here>', express.static(path.join(__dirname,'./static')));
```

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<something_here>/css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<something_here>/css/style.css">
```

Comment: @AkshitTrivedi, Good to hear, can you please accept the answer, if that works... Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add '/' in the path:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="css/style.css">
```

Also, you should make a change in your app file:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/static'));
```

This way express knows from where it has to serve the static files.

Answer (score 0):

You are serving the static folder at `/public` endpoint. So you should change the link to

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="/public/css/style.css">`

and

`<script src="/public/js/script.js"></script>`

Also check the name of the css file.

Comment: Already did this , but still getting error